# Is $\phi_f : \hom(Q,M) \rightarrow \hom(Q,N)$ monomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f : M \rightarrow N$ monomorphism of $R$-mod and let $Q$ a $R$-mod.

Then
$$\phi_f : \hom(Q,M) \rightarrow \hom(Q,N)$$
$$g \mapsto f\circ g$$
is monomorphism through the composition.

I know how prove that $\phi_f$ is morphism, the prove is let $r,s\in \hom(Q,M)$ then $(r+s)\in \hom(Q,M)$, implies  $\phi_f \left(r+s\right) = f \circ (r+s) = f \circ r + f \circ s = \phi_f \left(r\right) + \phi_f \left(s \right)$.

But, is $\phi_f$ monomorphism? I think that's false because only will be monomorphism if the element of $\hom(Q,M)$ is monomorphism.

Comment: You are confusing a few things: $f \circ g$ does not need to be mono, but just $\neq 0$ for each $g \neq 0$. (I edited my comment, since I misread something.)

Comment: Look up projective modules